# node js elementtree required get Cannot find module 'sax'

Tags: node.js, module

i am attempting to use elementtree in my node js server
however the following message is genearted on server startup

`Cannot find module 'sax'`

i had to install elementree from zip, what have i done wrong?

these are my rquire statements

`var cache = require('./node_modules/node-cache');`

`var elementTree = require('./node_modules/node-elementtree');`

this is my folder structure

`module\node_modules\node-cache`

`module\node_modules\node-elementtree`

my server js script resides in `\module`

Comment: Where in your code do you use `require('sax')`? Also why didn't you try `npm install elementtree` instead of installing from zip?

Comment: my site stops npm install from working my only option is to install from downloaded zip. my code does not require sax. the require sax that is failing is within the elementree js sub module 'sax'!, sax.js requires 'sax'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are not using npm for installing your node-elementtree module

[This](https://github.com/racker/node-elementtree/blob/master/package.json) is the `package.json` of node-elementtree. and it is clearly mentioned that there is a dependency on sax 0.3.5

```
"dependencies" : {
    "sax": "0.3.5"
  }
```

Incase if you had done `npm install` it would have resolved your dependency constraints.

Inside your node-elementtree module it uses sax [here](https://github.com/racker/node-elementtree/blob/master/lib/parsers/sax.js) and your require didn't resolve to a proper module. Hence the error. Incase you can't use npm then install sax too using zip if possible but it may increase your dependency list once again as the above. So, Try resolving npm issue

Also you don't need to use

```
var cache = require('./node_modules/node-cache');
var elementTree = require('./node_modules/node-elementtree');
```

in your code

```
var cache = require('node-cache');
var elementTree = require('node-elementtree');
```

the above would do. Node automatically locates the module from ./node_modules directory and even from many [more](http://itsallabtamil.blogspot.in/2012/01/nodejs-modules-and-export-explained.html) places

Comment: thanks Tamil for spending the time to explain. theres no way i can use npm to complete the install from the web. i managed to resolve the sax requirement by manually downloading the sax module and placing it in a folder called sax.